# Can you make an out-of-process COM+ run in STA Apartment?

Tags: .net, multithreading, com+

I have a third party umanaged STA COM dll that I am trying to run in a .Net multithreaded environment. At first I tried isolating the instances in separate AppDomains but since the DLL is unmanaged code that won't work. Then I have tried to wrap the unmanaged DLL in a .Net class and deploy it as a COM+ server so I can isolate each instance in its own process. This works except for the fact that COM+ is using MTA threadpool and instead of STA....which makes the calls to the unmanaged dll pretty slow. Is there anyway to force an out-of-process COM to use a particular thread model? Threads that are created instances of the COM+ object are STA but the threads in the COM+ server are MTA. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try changing the ThreadingModel registry value for your server from "Both" to "Apartment".

Comment: The apartment used to host a COM (including COM+) object is part of the definition of the COM class. While as @HansPassant notes you can change this in the registry, you will be breaking assumptions that the implementation makes about its runtime environment. That said switching to apartment is the least dangerous change. But if the COM type is explicitly STA it should register itself as such, if not report it as a bug to its authors.

Comment: Hmm, no, that's not the way it works.  Only requirement is to honor the threading model that the COM coclass requested and marshal the interface if there's a mismatch.  The CLR automatically provides this.  As the OP found out, it made his calls slow because COM created another thread to provide a safe home for his single-threaded helper object.  An STA thread is an optimization, not a requirement.

Comment: So am I better off just creating separate processes and communicating with named pipes? I tried changing the model type in the registry to STA but when installing the com service it said it could not because the object was not "poolable".